# choose among different arrays based on length in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of different 1-D numpy arrays that contain only numbers. Each vector has a different number of elements, and as a result each array has its own length. I want to choose the array with the most elements (i.e. greater length). The arrays are given as input and are not calculated/created by my code.

I can do it using a loop, but I am wondering if there is a nice way to do it in Python. Thank you.

Comment: One idiom you might consider is `max((f(thing), thing) for thing in things)` which will return the `f(thing), thing` pair with the largest `f(thing)` because of tuple ordering.

Comment: ...actually it's better to use `max(things, key=f)`. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is a list of numpy arrays,

```
import numpy as np 
a = [np.arange(np.random.randint(16)+1) for i in range(10)]
```

you can get the array with the maximum number of elements using

```
longest_array = max(a, key=len)
```